# matplotlib animation video not fitting in Jupyter_Notebook Cell

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Okay, so I am trying to create some animation in matplotlib. I am doing this on Jupyter-Notebook.

I am converting the animation using `to_html5_video()`. And displaying it using `HTML()`. The problem is that this video is not fitting in my cell.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
l, = ax.plot([],[], "k.")
ax.set_xlim([0,L])
ax.set_ylim([0,L])

def animate(i):
    l.set_data(xPos[:i], yPos[:i])

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,frames=len(xPos)).to_html5_video()
HTML(ani)
```

It is looking like this:
[image: As you can see, the video is not fitting the cell.]

How do I fit it properly?

Comment: The width of your notebook seems unusually small. But if that is restricted by something, you need to create a smaller figure or use a smaller dpi.

Answer (score 1):

When I had this problem I found that I could make the video smaller by using `plt.rcParams["savefig.dpi"] = 100`. This gave me the notion that my config was somehow bad, so I simply deleted `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc` and the sample code for animations now render correctly.